# JS Dom manipulation issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So i am creating a carousel generator framework and I want to make the implementation as simple as possible for the user. The developer is supposed to add
images without caring about design/responsiveness. The framework must take every image and insert it in a div with the classname of "slide". In this case from this code:

```
<div id="album" class="album">
        <img src="./assets/img1.jpeg" alt="img1">
        <img src="./assets/img2.jpeg" alt="img2">
        <img src="./assets/img3.jpeg" alt="img3">
        <img src="./assets/img4.jpeg" alt="img4">
        <img src="./assets/img5.jpeg" alt="img5">
        <img src="./assets/img6.jpeg" alt="img6">
    </div>
```

the framework should generate this:

```
<div class="slide">
        <img src="./assets/img1.jpeg" alt="img1">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="./assets/img2.jpeg" alt="img2">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="./assets/img3.jpeg" alt="img3">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="./assets/img4.jpeg" alt="img4">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="./assets/img5.jpeg" alt="img5">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="./assets/img6.jpeg" alt="img6">
    </div>
```

But the following code generates only 3 of the 6 images:

```
    let album = document.getElementById("album");

let nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
nextButton.addEventListener('', () => {
    album.scrollBy(window.innerWidth, 0);
})

Object.keys(album.children).forEach(key => {
    if (album.children[key].tagName === 'IMG') {
        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.className = "slide";
        newDiv.append(album.children[key]);
        album.replaceChild(newDiv, album.children[key]);
    }
})
```

and has an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined
    at Object.keys.forEach.key (index.js:9)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:8
```

and the generated carousel is:[image]

Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Object.keys(album.children).forEach(key,` **index** `=> {
    if (album.children[` **index** `].tagName === 'IMG') {` It's the second param of `forEach()` method that is the index.

Answer (score 7):

This happens because `.children` creates a *live collection* of [nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) so the iteration changes while you insert new children `div` inside the `forEach`

you could instead create a static collection like

```
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#album > img');
```

and iterate over that collection of nodes

```
let album = document.getElementById('album');
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#album > img');
Object.keys(nodes).forEach(i => {
   let slide = document.createElement('div');
   slide.className = 'slide';
   slide.appendChild(nodes[i]);
   album.appendChild(slide)
});
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgKmbx)

---

The generated source is

[image]

Comment: I changed it to this `let album = document.getElementById("album");
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#album > img');
nodes.forEach(node => {
        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.className = "slide";
        newDiv.append(node);
        console.log(newDiv)
})

` but now i get a new error because the child replacement is incorrect but i don't know how to change it.